# Include only form-field-theme in angular material 15

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to import only the component styles that I'm using in my angular material 15 theme, but for form-field it doesn't work:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use 'theme-light' as light;

@include mat.core();
...

@include mat.input-theme(light.$ng-frontend-theme);
@include mat.list-theme(light.$ng-frontend-theme);
@include mat.private-form-field-theme(light.$ng-frontend-theme); // << Error here!!

...
```

Error message:

```
SassError: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
13 │ @include mat.private-form-field-theme(light.$ng-frontend-theme);
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  apps/ng-frontend/src/styles/material/_theme.scss 13:1  @use
  apps/ng-frontend/src/styles.scss 2:1                   root stylesheet
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to just write the mixin name, it will work, despite the editor can not find the mixin.

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
$palette: mat.define-palette(mat.$lime-palette);
$theme: mat.define-light-theme(
      (
         color: (
            primary: mat.define-palette($palette),
            accent: mat.define-palette($palette),
         ),
         typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
         density: 0,
      )
);
    
// Material styles
@include mat.core-theme($theme);
@include mat.button-theme($theme);
@include mat.form-field-theme($theme);
@include mat.input-theme($theme);
@include mat.select-theme($theme);

//@include mat.core-theme($theme);
//@include mat.card-theme($theme);
//@include mat.progress-bar-theme($theme);
//@include mat.tooltip-theme($theme);
//@include mat.form-field-theme($theme);
//@include mat.input-theme($theme);
//@include mat.select-theme($theme);
//@include mat.autocomplete-theme($theme);
//@include mat.dialog-theme($theme);
//@include mat.chips-theme($theme);
//@include mat.slide-toggle-theme($theme);
//@include mat.radio-theme($theme);
//@include mat.slider-theme($theme);
//@include mat.menu-theme($theme);
//@include mat.list-theme($theme);
//@include mat.paginator-theme($theme);
//@include mat.tabs-theme($theme);
//@include mat.checkbox-theme($theme);
//@include mat.button-theme($theme);
//@include mat.icon-button-theme($theme);
//@include mat.fab-theme($theme);
//@include mat.snack-bar-theme($theme);
//@include mat.table-theme($theme);
//@include mat.progress-spinner-theme($theme);
//@include mat.badge-theme($theme);
//@include mat.bottom-sheet-theme($theme);
//@include mat.button-toggle-theme($theme);
//@include mat.datepicker-theme($theme);
//@include mat.divider-theme($theme);
//@include mat.expansion-theme($theme);
//@include mat.grid-list-theme($theme);
//@include mat.icon-theme($theme);
//@include mat.sidenav-theme($theme);
//@include mat.stepper-theme($theme);
//@include mat.sort-theme($theme);
//@include mat.toolbar-theme($theme);
//@include mat.tree-theme($theme);
```